# default python not finding same modules that other pythons can. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, macos

Not sure how to explain it and can't seem to figure out why this is happening but I tried to install 'MySQLdb' from macports.

When I type 'python' and `import MySQLdb`, then it fails but when I launch python from `/opt/local/bin/python2.7` and do the same then it works perfectly.  I thought I'd be smart and see where the default python is pointing to and then point it to this one but thats when it starts getting strange.

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python

$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  24 Feb 13 13:55 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

I don't understand, it seems to be pointing the the one that works but I can't load the same module as I can when I open python with the full path.

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, so any help to explain why this is happening would be great.

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

Comment: Is this homebrew or macports?

Comment: could you post the backtrace? in most cases this gives us some starting pointers...

Comment: I just updated the answer with the error message when it fails(when it works it just works)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `linux`? I can't find anything Linux-related in it.

Comment: Highly recommend removing all trace of macports from your system, install [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and follow the [homebrew python instructions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python)

Comment: jterrace: Not a very useful suggestion.  MacPorts is a perfectly legitimate and useful solution to installing MySQL with Python and the OP's problem has nothing to do with MacPorts per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python version banner you show is from yet another Python, that of the python.org 2.7.2 64-bit/32-bit installer downloaded from python.org.  It is not a MacPorts Python.  There should be a symlink to it at `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.  Apparently, the PATH environment variable in the terminal session you are using is not what you think it is or possibly you have a shell alias defined.  Try:

```
echo $PATH
```

You need to ensure that the MacPorts Python directory (`/opt/local/bin`) comes before that of the python.org Python (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Version/2.7/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`).

UPDATE:  Also check the current value of the MacPorts `port select` command.  It may be pointing at a non MacPorts Python.

```
$ sudo port select --list python
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
    python32
```

Comment: Thanks, its so weird, I did a echo $PATH and it seems to already be in the correct order: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Have you used the MacPorts `port select` command?  See update.

Comment: when I do port select command you have above, I get the exact same list as you(except I do not have python32), the same python27 is active for me as well..If they are all apple, and the python from the website is active, does that mean the macports version is not showing up?

Comment: The unlabeled python27 option *should* be referring to the MacPorts version, not the python.org version.